# How to prevent celery.backend_cleanup from executing in default queue

Tags: celery, celerybeat

I am using python + flask + SQS and I'm also using celery beat to execute some scheduled tasks.

Recently I went from having one single default "celery" queue to execute all my tasks to having dedicated queues/workers for each task. This includes tasks scheduled by celery beat which now all go to a queue named "scheduler".

Before dropping the "celery" queue, I monitored it to see if any tasks would wind up in that queue. To my surprise, they did.

Since I had no worker consuming from that queue, I could easily inspect the messages which piled up using the AWS console. What is saw was that all tasks were celery.backend_cleanup!!!

I cannot find out from the celery docs how do I prevent this celery.backend_cleanup from getting tossed into this default "celery" queue which I want to get rid of! And the [docs on beat](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/reference/cli.html#celery-beat) do not show an option to pass a queue name. So how do I do this?

This is how I am starting celery beat:

```
/venv/bin/celery -A backend.app.celery beat -l info --pidfile=
```

And this is how I am starting the worker

```
/venv/bin/celery -A backend.app.celery worker -l info -c 2 -Ofair -Q scheduler
```

Keep in mind, I don't want to stop backend_cleanup from executing, I just want it to go in whatever queue I specify.

Thanks ahead for the assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override this in the beat task setup.  You could also change the scheduled time to run here if you wanted to.

```
app.conf.beat_schedule = {
   'backend_cleanup': {
       'task': 'celery.backend_cleanup',
       'options': {'queue': <name>,
                   'exchange': <name>,
                   'routing_key': <name>}
   }
}
```

Comment: This seemed to indeed route the task to the queue that I wanted. However, now I have 2 of the same tasks executing. I have a task called "backend_cleanup" but also still the internal celery beat one "celery.backend_cleanup" both executing at the same time. I believe I still need to disable the built-in one by setting result_expires = None